# How to add value to the input field according to the active input with react-simple-keyboard?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-simple-keyboard

I have 3 input fields on my page. To fill in these inputs, it is not by what the user types, but by what the user presses on the `<Keyboard />` component of the `react-simple-keyboard` library.

I'm managing to save what the user presses on the `<Keyboard />` component. The problem is that I'm not able to separate the fields. For example, what I type in the 1st input is also going in the 2nd and 3rd input.

In `<Keyboard />` we have a prop called `onInit`. I believe the problem is in how I am manipulating this prop. But I don't know how to fix this. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

It's easier to understand with the codes and images below:
Here's my code I put into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/custom-keyboard-with-form-m2rrrw?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A13%2C3)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CustomKeyboard } from "./components";
import { KeyboardEnum } from "./components/CustomKeyboard/KeyboardEnum";
import "./styles.css";

interface InputValuesProps {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
  field3: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("");
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState<InputValuesProps>({
    field1: "",
    field2: "",
    field3: "",
  });
  const [activeInput, setActiveInput] =
    useState<keyof InputValuesProps>("field1");

  const onChange = (input: string) => {
    setInputValues({ ...inputValues, [activeInput]: input });

    setInputValue(input);
  };

  console.log("inputValues: ", inputValues);

  const onInputFocus = (inputName: any) => {
    setActiveInput(inputName);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValues.field1}
        onClick={() => onInputFocus("field1")}
        onChange={() => {}}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValues.field2}
        onClick={() => onInputFocus("field2")}
        onChange={() => {}}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValues.field3}
        onClick={() => onInputFocus("field3")}
        onChange={() => {}}
      />
      <CustomKeyboard
        startValue={inputValue}
        keyboardOnChange={onChange}
        layoutName={KeyboardEnum.Numbers}
        maxCharacters={16}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


// CustomKeyboard component
import React, { useEffect, useInsertionEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Keyboard from "react-simple-keyboard";
import { KeyboardEnum } from "./KeyboardEnum";
import "./index.css";

export interface CustomKeyboardProps {
  startValue: string;
  keyboardOnChange: (inputValue: string) => void;
  layoutName:
    | KeyboardEnum.Numbers
    | KeyboardEnum.Alphabet
    | KeyboardEnum.Symbols
    | KeyboardEnum.Shift;
  maxCharacters: number;
}

const CustomKeyboard = (props: CustomKeyboardProps) => {
  const [layoutName, setLayoutName] = useState(props.layoutName);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(props.startValue);
  const keyboardRef = useRef();
  const handleShift = (button: string): void => {
    switch (button) {
      case "{enter}":
        setInputValue("");
        props.keyboardOnChange(inputValue);
        break;
      case "{shift}":
        setLayoutName(
          layoutName === KeyboardEnum.Alphabet
            ? KeyboardEnum.Shift
            : KeyboardEnum.Alphabet
        );
        break;
      case "{numbers}":
        setLayoutName(KeyboardEnum.Numbers);
        break;
      case "{abc}":
        setLayoutName(KeyboardEnum.Alphabet);
        break;
      case "{symbols}":
        setLayoutName(KeyboardEnum.Symbols);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const onKeyPress = (button: string): void => {
    if (button === "{backspace}" && inputValue && inputValue.length === 1) {
      setInputValue("");
    }

    if (
      button === "{numbers}" ||
      button === "{abc}" ||
      button === "{shift}" ||
      button === "{symbols}" ||
      button === "{enter}"
    )
      handleShift(button);
  };

  const onChange = (input: string) => {
    const _input = input.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if (/^\d*$/.test(_input) && _input.length <= props.maxCharacters) {
      setInputValue(_input);
      if (keyboardRef.current) {
        try {
          // @ts-ignore
          keyboardRef.current.setInput(_input);
        } catch {
          console.log("Keyboard error");
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const customLayout = {
    numbers: [
      "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 {backspace}",
      // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
      "@ # $ % * ( ) ' \" {enter}",
      // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
      "{symbols} % - + = / ; : , . {symbols}",
      "{abc} {space} {abc}",
    ],
    shift: [
      "Q W E R T Y U I O P {backspace}",
      "A S D F G H J K L {enter}",
      "{shift} Z X C V B N M ! ? {shift}",
      "{numbers} , {space} . {numbers}",
    ],
    symbols: [
      "[ ] { } # % ^ * + = {backspace}",
      "_ \\ | ~ < > € £ ¥ ·",
      // eslint-disable-next-line quotes
      "{numbers} . , ? ! ' {enter}",
      "{abc} {space} {abc}",
    ],
    abc: [
      "q w e r t y u i o p {backspace}",
      "a s d f g h j k l {enter}",
      "{shift} z x c v b n m ! ? {shift}",
      "{numbers} , {space} . {numbers}",
    ],
  };

  const customDisplay = {
    "{numbers}": "123",
    "{shift}": "⇧",
    "{space}": "space",
    "{backspace}": "⌫",
    "{abc}": "ABC",
    "{symbols}": "#+=",
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.keyboardOnChange && props.keyboardOnChange(inputValue);
  }, [inputValue]);

  return (
    <div className="bg-[#263238] flex h-[418px] justify-center items-center w-full shadow-2xl p-6 absolute bottom-0">
      <div className="w-[1094px]">
        <Keyboard
          onInit={(e) => e.setInput(inputValue)}
          keyboardRef={(r) => (keyboardRef.current = r)}
          theme={"hg-theme-default myTheme1"}
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
          layoutName={layoutName}
          layout={customLayout}
          display={customDisplay}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomKeyboard;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the focus, you need to update your input value:

```js
  const onInputFocus = (inputName: any) => {
    setActiveInput(inputName);
    setInputValue(inputValues[inputName]);
  };
```

Right now, the last input value is being carried over when the focus changes.

---

*Additionally,* you will need to update the `keyboardRef.current` whenever `props.startValue`. However, you will also need to take steps to ensure that you don't have circular updates on change.

I think that your conjecture concerning `onInit` is correct: the `Keyboard` component is almost certainly not re-rendered/initialized each time you change your `startValue`.

Without a MRE, it is hard to suggest further fixes.

Comment: Hi Webelo, thank you, but that doesn't work "/

Comment: Please simplify your example so that it can be run locally and provide some more info about why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry webelo, my mistake. It's works perfectly for me.. Thank you!!!